# OpenGL Rotation relative to object axis

Tags: qt, opengl, rotation, local, axis

I'm struggling with the rotation of an object. I want to illustrate the gyro readings from my AR Drone 2.0 with this little program.
Maybe you want watch this short video first: http://youtu.be/HvrLS8Olr2c

The sliders are for x,y,z rotation that is done with

```
glRotatef(rotationX, x_vect.x, x_vect.y, x_vect.z);
glRotatef(rotationY, y_vect.x, y_vect.y, y_vect.z);
glRotatef(rotationZ, z_vect.x, z_vect.y, z_vect.z);
```

where the values are:

```
Vector x_vect = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
Vector y_vect = {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
Vector z_vect = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
```

You can download the full source code of this small app from here: http://ablage.stabentheiner.de/2013-01-21_openglimportmodel.zip

The problem is that if you rotate let's say the Y axis first and then try to play with the X-slider it won't pivot the axis it should do (see C4D animation for comparison). I think it's because I perform the X rotation first and then the Y rotation. Swapping the lines of code doesn't solve the problem but pushes it to another axis..

Answer (score 3):

It happens because when you call `glRotatef()` the object's pivot will rotate. Take a look at this beautiful die:
[image: awesome d6]

Imagine the x axis running through 4 and 3 (opposite sides on a d6 always add up to 7), the z axis running through 6 and 1, and the y axis running through 2 and 5.
If you would write this code:

```
glRotatef(90,1,0,0);
glRotatef(90,0,1,0);
```

The die would first rotate 90 degrees around it's x axis, making 6 the side at the top. However, the axis stay relative to the die, so the next call would stay rotate the die around the axis running through 2 and 5, effectively rotating the side with 6 to the right. When you turn these calls around, and make the die rotate around it's y axis first, the side with the 6 will go to the right first and and at the top.

Now, with that out of the way. What you could do is rotate the camera around the object, instead of rotating the object itself. I suggest reading about implementing an arcball camera. [This seems like a good start.](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/arcball_rotation/19003/)

Answer (score 1):

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/opengl-grabber.html

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/opengl-grabber-glwidget-cpp.html

When I was doing rotations in opengl in Qt, the grabber example was very helpful.  Here is a bit from the glwidget.cpp .

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

 glPushMatrix();
// Here is the rotation code:
 glRotated(xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
 glRotated(yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
 glRotated(zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

 drawGear(gear1, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, gear1Rot / 16.0);
 drawGear(gear2, +3.1, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0 * (gear1Rot / 16.0) - 9.0);

 glRotated(+90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
 drawGear(gear3, -3.1, -1.8, -2.2, +2.0 * (gear1Rot / 16.0) - 2.0);

 glPopMatrix();
}
```